# How do I check if proportion of values in list are mostly positive?

Tags: list-manipulation, expression-test

I'd like to return a a boolean variable that tells me whether numbers in a list are mostly positive. 
For example:

```
a = {3,2,3,4,-1,-2,-5,3}
```

There are 5 positive values and 3 negative ones in list a. That is, 5/8 of the values (more than 50% of them) are positive. How do I get a boolean variable that tells me if this is true or not.

Comment: `mostlyPos[a_?VectorQ] := (Count[a, _?Positive]/Length[a]) > 1/2;`

Comment: Or `mostlyPos[a_?VectorQ] := Mean[Unitstep[a-1]]>1/2` (works only for vectors of integers).

Answer (score 12):

My favorite way, out of many possibilities:

```
Majority @@ Positive[{3, 2, 3, 4, -1, -2, -5, 3}]
   True

Majority @@ Positive[{-100, -200, -300, 10, 1000000}]
   False
```

(Change `Positive[]` to `NonNegative[]` if wanted.)

Answer (score 7):

Here is one way:

```
mp[l_] := Total[Sign[l]] > 0

mp[a]
(* True *)

mp[{0, 0, 0}]
(* False *)

mp[{-100, -200, -300, 10, 1000000}]
(* False *)
```

As written, `mp` uses a strictly positive test.  If desired, we can relax that by changing the test from `... > 0` to `... >= 0` in which case zeroes and equal counts of positives and negatives will be treated as "mostly positive".

Answer (score 3):

```
mP = Median @ # > 0 &;

mP @ {3, 2, 3, 4, -1, -2, -5, 3}
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Alternatively, `mP = Positive @* Median`.

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {3, 2, 3, 4, -1, -2, -5, 3, 0};
```

Using `GroupBy`

```
g = GroupBy[list, Positive]
```

<|True -> {3, 2, 3, 4, 3}, False -> {-1, -2, -5, 0}|>

```
First @ Keys @ MaximalBy[Length] @ g
```

True

Answer (score 1):

```
l1 = {3, 2, 3, 4, -1, -2, -5, 3, 0};
l2 = {-100, -200, -300, 10, 1000000};
```

Using `CountsBy` and `MaximalBy`:

```
First@Keys@MaximalBy[CountsBy[l1, Positive], "Value"]

(*True*)

First@Keys@MaximalBy[CountsBy[l2, Positive], "Value"]

(*False*)
```